# Why is my boot speed so low?

Tags: 16.04, boot, dell, 64-bit

I recently upgraded my computer from 32 bit ubuntu 14 to 64 bit ubuntu 16. My computer takes much longer to boot now. When I boot I see the dell logo and loading screen for 5 seconds and then I get a black screen for 50 seconds. After that I get a screen that shows a lot of [ OK ] 's and other text. This shows for about 30 seconds and then it shows my lockscreen. I am not satisfied with my 1:30 boot time and am wondering if there is a fix. I am on a Dell Inspiron 1525 and want to know if there is a way that I can speed up the boot.
After running `systemd-analyze blame | head -n 10` I got these results

```
    16.294s dev-sda1.device
    15.127s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
    11.512s irqbalance.service
    11.447s grub-common.service
    11.398s ondemand.service
    11.387s speech-dispatcher.service
    10.328s apport.service
    10.192s lightdm.service
     9.473s systemd-udevd.service
```

Comment: There's really not enough information to know what specifically is causing this issue for you. I've got two Dell laptops, and both boot to login screen in a few seconds (3-5ish). You likely have some service installed, or configuration, which is causing this delay, but since you've provided literally no details beyond "it is slow," it's impossible to say what it might be.

Comment: Please run `systemd-analyze blame | head -n 10` , and [edit] your question to include it. This shows what took time.